# Web API using Odata returns BSON while expecting Response as JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, odata

I literally followed this tutorial,
http://jerther.blogspot.com/2014/11/aspnet-web-api-2-help-pages-odata_28.html

Excepting the return format as JSON but not sure how am getting back BSON, am new to BSON never heard about.

OData, WebAPI, EF (repository pattern)is what am using. Any suggestions on how to get back JSON instead of BSON.

Here is my Code, what i did so far

**WebApiConfig:**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            // config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            // config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API routes           
            // Remove the XML formatter
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);                
            config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

**ODataConfig.cs - used it in the routeConfig.cs**

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); //This has to be called before the following OData mapping, so also before WebApi mapping
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<Item>("Item");
            config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "api", builder.GetEdmModel());
        }
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

**Controller.**

```
        [EnableQuery]
        [ODataRoute]
        public IQueryable<Item> GetItem()
        {
            var result = _cRepository.GetAll();            
            return result.AsQueryable();
        }
```

[image: Response]

Comment: Yes, please try to show is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: `I can share my code if Needed.` S.O is for answering specific coding problems. So it is really what you should do (but not a wall of text, a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please).

Comment: I can't see the code where you get BSON

Comment: @EZI thanks for your responses, The response from the controller result.AsQueryable(); I should receive JSON but for some reason the response content-type is Application/bson

Comment: Can you post your Request Headers? It's possible that the request is asking for BSON back and Web API is obliging. Check out the information on content negotiation here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation

Comment: Accept: Application/JSON is what am asking.

Comment: con't repro either, why not try some samples in https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4

Comment: I spent a whole day, I can't figure it out why the heck it returns me application/BSON, is it a serialization problem ? , @FanOuyang I will try to implement the same in a different solution, will let you guys know if it works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Controller was referencing to System.Web.Http.OData, uninstalled all the nuget packages related to Odata,WebAPI and reinstalled. Referenced Controller to System.Web.OData and everything looks good now returns JSON. Thanks a lot for all your responses.